# Can I have a method in JAVA with generic object parameter

Tags: java

I have a method

```
public int addTransaction(Transactions tr){
  //etc...

}
```

and now I want to create a new method, which will do exactly like `addTransaction` but it will take a different type object `Order order`.

I realise that I can create this:

```
public int addTransaction(Order tr){
  //etc...

}
```

However I was wondering if I can have one method with generic type inside the parenthesis so to pass whatever object I want. Can this be done?

Comment: Can we do: `public class SOTest<T> {public int addTransaction(T tr){}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you pass any object using generics? Yes. You do it like this:

```
public <T> int addTransaction(T tr) {
    // ...
}
```

The question is, though, what does that do for you? That incantation is equivalent to

```
public int addTransaction(Object tr) {
    // ...
}
```

since the `T` is unconstrained. Either way, all you can really do with `tr` is invoke methods declared/defined on `Object`.

Now, if there is some common parent type that `Transaction` and `Order` (and anyone else) share, then things start to make a little more sense. If the common parent type is `Parent`, then you can write something like

```
public <T extends Parent> int addTransaction(T tr) {
    // ...
}
```

and you can now treat `tr` as in instance of `Parent`. But what does that give you over the following?

```
public int addTransaction(Parent tr) {
    // ...
}
```

Nothing that I can see.

So, bottom line, yes you can do such a thing, but the value of doing it is suspect.

Answer (score 2):

Generic methods are created as follows

```
public <T> int addTransaction(T tr){
    //TODO:
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The use of generics here is unnecessary: you might as well simply use `Object`.

Comment: That could be also used!

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a superclass/subclass relationship between `Order` and `Transactions`, no. And if there is such a relationship, you simply need the overload which takes the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

`Transaction` and `Order` will need to both extend from the same `Class` or implement the same `Interface`, or one will need to extend the other in order for this to work.

Here are a couple of examples:

One `Class` extending the other:

```
public class Test {

    public int addTransaction (final Transaction tr) {

    }
}

class Transaction {

}

class Order extends Transaction {

}
```

Both sharing a common `Interface:`

```
public class Test {

    public int addTransaction (final Process tr) {

    }
}

interface Process {

}

class Transaction implements Process {

}

class Order implements Process {

}
```